# Realizar busqueda y comparacion < ó >

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Buen dia

Tengo mi siguiente codigo realizado en VBA EXCEL estoy realizando una macro que realice una busqueda y si lo encuentra realice la comparacion < ó > que el campo que tiene se los simplifico tengo 3 columnas en mi excel

- Material Number
- QA04
- RACKS

Las columnas QA04 y RACKS me sirven para saber en cual de los 2 o en ambas locaciones cuento con piezas en existencia lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de buscar el material number si lo encuentra me haga la comparacion si la cantidad que encuentre en RACKS < (menor que) 0 entonces me arroje este mensaje "Necesita iniciar preconteo de material para mandar a rack" y si es > (Mayor que) 0 entonces no me muestre nada y continuo revisando.

Mas que nada requiero una orientacion ya que me bloquie ya que al realizar la busqueda solo me muestra las columnas y no es lo que requiero.

Si alguien pudiera orientarme o recomendarme algunos blogs para tomar camino

Actualmente asi esta mi formulario [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi esta el codigo actualmente con la ayuda de una persona del foro solo no muestra el mensaje

```
Private Sub Texto_Change()

 With Worksheets("WMSR0290")

  For fila = 3 To .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   If UCase(.Cells(fila, 2).Value) = UCase(Me.Texto.Value) Then ' compara la columna A = Material Number
     
    If .Cells(fila, 4).Value <= 0 Then                          ' Compara La columna B = QA04
      
     MsgBox "Necesita iniciar preconteo de material para mandar a rack"
     
    End If
        End If
       Next
End With

End Sub
```

Estos son un poco de los datos que me tengo en mi tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Es complicado ayudarte sin tener tus datos.

Comment: Ya añadi a mi pregunta un poco de mis datos

Comment: @AbrahamValencia sabes que lo que quiero es que si de la columna rack's el vlaor es <=0 me muestre un mensaje en el textbox2 que diga que hay que contar material para mandar a rack

Comment: Tu código tendrá que mirar a la columna Racks. `Worksheets("WMSR0290").Cells(fila, 2).Value` mira a la columna 2 (la B) así que entiendo que la d eRACKS es la 4 (la D). Añadir algo tipo `If Worksheets("WMSR0290").Cells(fila, 4).Value<=0 Then....` por ahí deben ir los tiros.

Comment: Que tal Esei de echo utilice el codigo que dejo una persona de aqui del foro como base pero le comento que no me arroja el mensaje no se si me podrias auxiliar

Comment: De echo ya añadi el nuevo codigo a la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

te paso como seria , ten en cuenta lo que dice Abraham. saludos

```
Private Sub Texto_Change()

 With Worksheets("WMSR0290")

  For fila = 2 To .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   If UCase(.Cells(fila, 1).Value) = UCase(Me.Texto.Value) Then ' compara la columna A = Material Number
     
    If .Cells(fila, 2).Value <= 0 Then                          ' Compara La columna B = QA04
      
     MsgBox "Necesita iniciar preconteo de material para mandar a rack"
     
    End If
        End If
       Next   
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Buen dia ya modifique la publicacion y añadi una imagen con un poco de lo datos que tengo en mi tabla

Comment: Ya añadi el codigo y lo compile pero no me muestra ningun error ingreso el numero de material pero no me muestra ningun mensaje ni error que me diga si lo finalizo o debugueo