# Busqueda con comparacion <= y >=

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Cuento con el siguiente codigo para realizar una busqueda en 3 columnas las cuales son:

1. Material Number
2. QA04
3. RACKS

Quiero que al ingresar el Material Number me haga una comparacion contra la columna racks en la cual la condicion seria si el valor que hay en la celda es <=0 entonces me muestre el siguiente mensaje en el 2do textbox "Sin material en Racks iniciar preconteo" y en caso de que el valor sea >=1 entonces no me muestre ningun mensaje y continue con el escaneo de material.

Este es el codigo:

```
Private Sub Texto_Change()

 With Worksheets("WMSR0290")

  For fila = 3 To .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   If UCase(.Cells(fila, 2).Value) = UCase(Me.Texto.Value) Then ' compara la columna B = Material Number
     
    If .Cells(fila, 4).Value <= 0 Then                          ' Compara La columna D = RACKS
      
     MsgBox "Sin material en Racks iniciar preconteo"
     
    End If
        End If
       Next
End With

End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los datos que tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo consegui con ayuda de un compañero pero no logro que me muestre el mensaje ni que realice la comparacion.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Realizar busqueda y comparacion < ó >](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/558577/realizar-busqueda-y-comparacion-%c3%b3)

Comment: Sabes que como se perdio la pregunta la resuvi pero me quede donde mismo con el codigo no me muestra error pero tampoco me muestra el mensaje

Comment: Pero el dato "Número material" necesitas compararlo en algún momento? Es decir, tu condición es que la cantidad en la columna RACKS sea únicamente <=0 o también tienes que comprobar que el material exista y la cantidad sea <=0?

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas comprobar si el material existe en rack tendrás que comprobar tanto el material como la cantidad, para ello tienes que hacer la comparación al mismo nivel, en el mismo IF. Así te comprueba si el material que buscas existe en la tabla y, si su cantidad es <= 0 te muestra el mensaje. Si existe pero su cantidad es mayor que cero continuará escaneando:

```
Private Sub Texto_Change()
    With Worksheets("WMSR0290")
        For fila = 3 To .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If UCase(.Cells(fila, 2).Value) = UCase(Me.Texto.Value) And .Cells(fila, 4).Value <= 0 Then
                MsgBox "Sin material en Racks iniciar preconteo"
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Otra cosa, no entiendo el uso de UCase con valores. Si no vas a escribir texto te puedes ahorrar los Ucase, que no pintan nada.

De todas formas tampoco entiendo que teniendo ya una pregunta abierta abras otra idéntica. Tienes que utilizar la pregunta original...